# Fill between absolute value function and x-axis

Tags: fillbetween

I am trying to shade the area between an absolute value function and the x-axis on a given interval. It is working for one equation, and not working for another. Could someone help troubleshoot the issue?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=3,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
     enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
     xmin=-3, xmax=3
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-2.001:3,samples=100,smooth,blue, very thick, name path=A] {abs(2*x)-1}; 
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B] {0};    
    \addplot[blue!15!white] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-2:3}];     
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=3,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
     enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
     xmin=0, xmax=8
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:8, samples=100,smooth,blue, very thick, name path=A] {2-abs(x-5)}; 
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B] {0};    
    \addplot[blue!15!white] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=0:8}];     
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What is causing the weird shading issue on the second graph?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You need to define `domain` for both paths, i.e.; for `A` and `B`. The shorter way is define it in `axis` preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=3,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
     enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
     xmin=-3, xmax=3,
     domain=-2:3,samples=100  % <----
    ]
    \addplot[blue, very thick, name path=A] {abs(2*x)-1};
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B] {0};
    \addplot[blue!15!white] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-2:3}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}%
    [grid=both,
     minor tick num=3,
     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
     major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
     axis lines=middle,
     enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
     xmin=0, xmax=8,
     domain=0:8, samples=100  % <----
    ]
    \addplot[blue, very thick, name path=A] {2-abs(x-5)};
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B] {0};
    \addplot[blue!15!white] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=0:8}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!